# Input matrix to opencv kmeans clustering

Tags: opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

This question is specific to opencv:
The kmeans example given in the opencv documentation has a 2-channel matrix - one channel for each dimension of the feature vector. But, some of the other example seem to say that it should be a one channel matrix with features along the columns with one row for each sample. Which of these is right?

if I have a 5 dimensional feature vector, what should be the input matrix that I use:
This one:

```
cv::Mat inputSamples(numSamples, 1, CV32FC(numFeatures))
```

or this one:

```
cv::Mat inputSamples(numSamples, numFeatures, CV_32F)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The correct answer is `cv::Mat inputSamples(numSamples, numFeatures, CV_32F)`.
The OpenCV Documentation about `kmeans` [says](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html):

> samples – Floating-point matrix of input samples, one row per sample

So it is not a Floating-point vector of n-Dimensional floats as in the other option. Which examples suggested such a behaviour?

Here is also a small example by me that shows how kmeans can be used. It clusters the pixels of an image and displays the result:

```cpp
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat src = imread( argv[1], 1 );
  Mat samples(src.rows * src.cols, 3, CV_32F);
  for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
    for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++ )
      for( int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
        samples.at<float>(y + x*src.rows, z) = src.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[z];


  int clusterCount = 15;
  Mat labels;
  int attempts = 5;
  Mat centers;
  kmeans(samples, clusterCount, labels, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10000, 0.0001), attempts, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers );


  Mat new_image( src.size(), src.type() );
  for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
    for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++ )
    { 
      int cluster_idx = labels.at<int>(y + x*src.rows,0);
      new_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[0] = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx, 0);
      new_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[1] = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx, 1);
      new_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[2] = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx, 2);
    }
  imshow( "clustered image", new_image );
  waitKey( 0 );
}
```

Comment: I would like to know what you are doing in the loop before the clusterCount variable declaration and also what you are doing at the end in the for after the kmeans. Do you think it's possible to update the answer with this information? Thanks!

Comment: The first loop reorders the data from the image from a (rows,cols,3) matrix to an (rows*cols,3) matrix (one row per pixel). The loop at the end replaces each pixel in the image with the corresponding cluster center for visualization.

Comment: Is it possible to use `Mat::reshape()` instead of nested for loops?

Comment: The indexing is wrong on the final conversion it should be  int cluster_idx = bestLabels.at<int>(x + y*img.cols,0);

Comment: Why are you reordering the data weirdly like this? From the loop it seems like the first row of the image is now going to be 0, 10, 20, 30... row of samples and second row is going to be at 1, 11, 21, 31...

Answer (score 2):

As alternative to reshaping the input matrix manually, you can use OpenCV [reshape](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=copy#mat-reshape) function to achieve similar result with less code. Here is my working implementation of reducing colors count with K-Means method (in Java):

```java
private final static int MAX_ITER = 10;
private final static int CLUSTERS = 16;

public static Mat colorMapKMeans(Mat img, int K, int maxIterations) {

    Mat m = img.reshape(1, img.rows() * img.cols());
    m.convertTo(m, CvType.CV_32F);

    Mat bestLabels = new Mat(m.rows(), 1, CvType.CV_8U);
    Mat centroids = new Mat(K, 1, CvType.CV_32F);
    Core.kmeans(m, K, bestLabels, 
                new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.COUNT | TermCriteria.EPS, maxIterations, 1E-5),
                1, Core.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS, centroids);
    List<Integer> idx = new ArrayList<>(m.rows());
    Converters.Mat_to_vector_int(bestLabels, idx);

    Mat imgMapped = new Mat(m.size(), m.type());
    for(int i = 0; i < idx.size(); i++) {
        Mat row = imgMapped.row(i);
        centroids.row(idx.get(i)).copyTo(row);
    }

    return imgMapped.reshape(3, img.rows());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Highgui.imwrite("result.png", 
        colorMapKMeans(Highgui.imread(args[0], Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR),
            CLUSTERS, MAX_ITER));
}
```

OpenCV reads image into 2 dimensional, 3 channel matrix. First call to `reshape` - `img.reshape(1, img.rows() * img.cols());` - essentially unrolls 3 channels into columns. In resulting matrix one row corresponds to one pixel of the input image, and 3 columns corresponds to RGB components.

After K-Means algorithm finished its work, and color mapping has been applied, we call `reshape` again - `imgMapped.reshape(3, img.rows())`, but now rolling columns back into channels, and reducing row numbers to the original image row number, thus getting back the original matrix format, but only with reduced colors.

Comment: I think you need to take care that the image is continuous first before taking this approach http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-iscontinuous

Comment: if you use clone ie. using clone as in  img.clone().reshape(1, img.rows() * img.cols()) then the image will be continuous (and your original image will be unchanged)